# Differences in behavior in Azure Function running in App Service plan and Consumption Plan. Why?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Differences in behavior in Azure Function running in App Service plan and Consumption Plan. Why?

I'm running the [WkHtmlToPdf.exe](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) as part as an Azure Function in an App Service Plan (B1). I would like to move this Azure Function to a Consumption plan, but it seems to fail.

I track down the blocking point to be the WkHtmlToPdf.exe, by using the Kudo console.

With an Azure Function in a Consumption plan, it just ends in a deadlock and never returns to the console.

Any ideas on this?

How it looks when running in a App Service Plan:
[image: Azure Function in an App Service plan]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by sandbox restrictions that do not apply to dedicated plans on Basic+ tiers.

You can find more information about the sandbox [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), and [this portion](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) of the documents covers PDF generation.